# Windows 7 - Unable to access shared folder as administrator

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I've encountered a problem on Windows 7. I have a shared folder created by an installer and I can't access it by the share name

> \\[machine_name]\[shared_folder_name]

Here are a few more details.

- The computer is registered in a domain.
- The user I log in with is a domain user added into the Administrators group
- The shared folder has full rights set up for the Administrators group of the local machine

I have no problem accessing the real folder on disk, but when I try to access it with the share name I get the following error

> You do not have permission to access \\[machine_name]\[shared_folder_name]. Contact your network administrator to request access.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any other NTFS permissions set that may be denying domain users or any other group your user account may be a part of.

Remember that deny's always override allow's.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm wondering if there's an explicit "Deny" assigned to a Guest or Network Users group, here.

Answer (score 1):

**Checking for Sticky Sessions**

Type `net use` on a command-line.

Sometimes you have previously connected to a share (even using UNC notation, e.g. \10.1.1.1\myshare) and even though you think you disconnected you really haven't.

So the next time you go to connect as a different user you're actually connecting as the same user.

From the command prompt you can explicitly disconnect a previous connection by typing `net use /delete` ...

**Checking permissions on share**

Even though you have admin rights on the local hard drive of the shared folder, you still need to inform Windows that the share has appropriate permissions.

Right click on your shared folder, choose "Sharing and security..", and then on the "Sharing" tab click on the "Permissions" button. You will usually see "Everyone" listed, and if you don't see either your username or "Administrator" then add them, and choose allow "Full Control" for that user/group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I discovered via event viewer.
Apparently the credentials for the share has been changed.
To check that goto: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager.
Find the machine name and check the user and password.
Did the trick for me. :)